# Converting video to .mp4 format after upload from local system does not show the video only hear sound

Tags: php, ffmpeg, mp4, video-conversion

I am using `fileuploader.js` to upload a video file. Now i want to convert the video format to `.mp4`. I have used `ffmpeg` and `php` to convert the video to `.mp4` after upload. The sample segment i used is

```
$converted = "uploads/".$uniqid.".mp4"; //$uniqid is the id for the video after upload
$cmd = "$ffmpeg -i $sourceUrl -f mp4 $converted"; //$sourceUrl is the path of the video
```

I have tried to convert `.flv` video file to `.mp4` format and it does but the problem is i cannot see the video only hear the sound after converting. Is the conversion line used in `$cmd` incorrect. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `ffmpeg -i source.flv output.mp4` should be enough, it will use default codecs for mp4. Can you paste the ffmpeg response to the above command?

Comment: I tried this but its not working for me. I tried the same in my local system and i am able to see the video but in server its not working. In my server ffmpeg version is 0.6 and in my local the version is 0.8. Is this the issue? Can you please tell how can i upgrade ffmpeg version in server from terminal.

Comment: Can you ssh into the server? If yes, follow these steps to upgrade: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1438052

Comment: Thanks but after running the third command i.e. `sudo apt-get install build-essential subversion git-core checkinstall yasm texi2html libfaac-dev libfaad-dev libmp3lame-dev libopencore-amrnb-dev libopencore-amrwb-dev libsdl1.2-dev libx11-dev libxfixes-dev libxvidcore4-dev zlib1g-dev` it is showing `E: Unable to locate package libxvidcore4-dev` and exit the installation

Comment: Search for libxvidcore4 using sudo apt-cache search libxvidcore , does this throw any options? May be a higher version is available now.